# How can I reconfigure openSUSE Leap's polkit to support having no root account?

Tags: sudo, opensuse, polkit

I recently installed OpenSUSE Leap on my laptop, and when I installed it I neglected to disable the `root` account. Since then I've disabled the `root` account, added the user `administrator_user` to the `wheel` group, tweaked the `sudoers` file so that I can use `sudo` as `administrator_user`, and disabled the `root` account.

`sudo` now works the way that I want it to, but everything involving `polkit` is borked up. I'm unable to use the GUI to make any changes that require `polkit` because `polkit` is asking for `root`'s password (which doesn't exist) instead of `administrator_user`'s password.

How do I get `polkit` to require `administrator_user`'s password instead of `root`'s password?

As an additional `polkit` configuration, how can I configure `polkit` to allow any user (including the unprivileged `regular_user`) to make changes to the WiFi configuration?

Comment: `root` is intrinsic to the way unix & linux work, ie, `id=0`, why on earth do you want to modify the system in such a way? If `administrator_user` has an id other than `0`, then you would need to update the kernel and many other applications.which check for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late, but try take a look at the following patch: [polkit-no-wheel-group](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/Base:System/polkit/polkit-no-wheel-group.patch?expand=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/441400)